# Finding Wireless Adapter in Debian

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, debian, adapter

I use a Macbook Pro 2012 . I had an urgent build to be done in linux , so installed Debian on a partition . However , it doesn't have an option of a wifi . 
Doing `lsusb` or `lspci` doesn't show the wifi adapter either .

Does anyone know what wifi adapter/driver Mac/OSX has ? and how that can be installed on Debian ?

Comment: I am very worried by your statement that your wifi card is not detected by `lspci`. This has nothing to do with having or not a driver for it (and, BTW, installing `wl` is a **terrible** idea).  Could you pls display the whole output of  `lspci -vnn | grep -A 6 -i net`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-Unibody-Early-2011-through-Mid-2012-Airport-Bluetooth-Board/IF161-083-1), the adapter is a Broadcom BCM94331PCIEBT4AX.

Looking on the [WikiDevi site](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM94331PCIEBT4), it states a couple of potential sources for the driver, suggesting it's in the `broadcom-wl` package. Information on getting this package can be found [here](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) (instructions copied below), or from an installer [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-b43-installer).

> 1. Add a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list for your Debian version, for example:
>
>    > Debian 8 "Jessie"
>    >
>    > `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`
> 2. Update the list of available packages. Install the relevant/latest
>      linux-image, linux-headers and broadcom-sta-dkms packages:
>
>    `# apt-get update`
>
>    `# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms`
>
>    > This will also install the recommended wireless-tools package. DKMS
>    >     will build the wl module for your system.
> 3. Unload conflicting modules:
>
>    `# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma`
> 4. Load the wl module:
>
>    `# modprobe wl`
> 5. Configure your wireless interface as appropriate. See also known
>      issues.